# How to do fast image processing in a WinRT application?

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm working on a WinRT app that should require some image processing.
i use the  `WriteableBitmapex`and  i try change color of particular pixel that on an ellipse in my image.
but my solution is very very slow. About several minutes after tap in image.
Why this solution is so slow? and What is the alternative way?

```
private void myimage_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var xcor = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement).X;
    var ycor = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement).Y;
    Image ws = sender as Image;

    int x = (int)(imag.PixelWidth * xcor / ws.ActualWidth);
    int y = (int)(imag.PixelHeight * ycor / ws.ActualHeight);
    var color = imag.GetPixel(x, y);
    if (color.B != 0 && color.G != 0 && color.R != 0)
    {
        while (color.B != 0 && color.G != 0 && color.R != 0 && x < imag.PixelWidth)
        {
            x = x+1;
            y = (int)(imag.PixelHeight * ycor / ws.ActualHeight);
            while (color.B != 0 && color.G != 0 && color.R != 0 && y < imag.PixelHeight)
            {
                y = y + 1;
                color = imag.GetPixel(x, y);
                imag.SetPixel(x, y, Colors.Red);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the coordinate you store in xcor,ycor?
what is that ellipse?
why do you stop your whiles when a pixel is black?

Comment: @Piglet i need change color of ellipse that stroke's color is black and xcor for Ensure clicking on the ellipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `BitmapContext`, because `Set/GetPixel` are *very very slow*, actually each time you call them they open/close a `BitmapContext`
2. Review your logic because honestly it doesn't make any sense to me, or explain what you're trying to achieve

**Here's an example on how to use a context along a few helpers:**

```
var bitmap = BitmapFactory.New(2048, 2048);
using (var context = bitmap.GetBitmapContext(ReadWriteMode.ReadWrite))
{
    Func<int, int, int> getPixel = (x, y) =>
    {
        var offset = y*bitmap.PixelWidth + x;
        return offset;
    };

    Action<int, int, int> setPixel = (x, y, c) =>
    {
        var offset = getPixel(x, y);
        context.Pixels[offset] = c;
    };

    Func<Color, int> toInt32 = c =>
    {
        var i = c.A << 24 | c.R << 16 | c.G << 8 | c.B;
        return i;
    };
    for (var y = 0; y < bitmap.PixelHeight; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.PixelHeight; x++)
        {
            var color = Color.FromArgb(
                255,
                (byte) ((float) x/bitmap.PixelWidth*255),
                (byte) ((float) y/bitmap.PixelHeight*255),
                255);
            var int32 = toInt32(color);
            setPixel(x, y, int32);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the same procedure used in Microsoft Paint? I try create tow tools like eraser and fill color in ms paint app. But I need to figure out what is a better way use this method or use graphic object? in this method I was able to create fill tools but for eraser in graphic method. how can use this tools for image in faster way?